# Is this function one-to-one, onto, both or not a function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics

$P(N) \times P(N) \to P(N)$ defined by $f(A,B)=A \cup B$.

Answer: I gave a counterexample for one-to-one because if $A=\{\{\},\{1,2\},\{1\},\{2\}\}$ and $B=\{\{\},\{2\},\{3\},\{2,3\}\}$ then $A \cup B = \{\{\},\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\}$,but $n(A \cup B) = 5$. This cannot be written in the for of $2^k, k \epsilon Z$.

I think it is onto because the $range = codomain$. I am not really sure if I have to prove this more or if that is sufficient (or I am completely wrong).

Answer (score 1):

You might want a bit more proof that this function is onto.

Hint: Let $A = \emptyset$.